# JavaSrcript not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a simple login / register form I've created:        https://codepen.io/adambdnr/pen/XpzRyN

It works really well here, but as soon as I want to make it work (like the click function to change between login and registration) in my real Spring application, it doesn't change, I only see the login page, nothing happens if I click to register. I was trying document.ready(function.. but I'm not sure what is wrong here:

```
$(function() {
     $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

(In the codepen, I've deleted the first DOCTYPE line from the HTML)

My file structure looks like:

resources

__static

____css

______style.css

____js

______login_register.js

__templates

____index.html

Comment: Have you [checked your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) Could you describe what you expect to happen in addition to what you're actually seeing?

Comment: it works in your code pen (buttons seem to correctly switch between forms), so whatever issue you're having I don't think you're describing it well enough

Comment: @MikeC I tought it could be something with the href attribute, but I actually tried everything.

Comment: @chiliNUT I want to be able to change the input field, when I click on the Login or the Register button, but when the page loads, and I click to the registration field, nothing happens

Comment: If nothing works it's likely to be a syntax error. Have you checked the console for issues? Maybe you can edit the post with the console log.

Comment: Did you add <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> after declaration of jQuery?

Comment: The problem was using my custom js file before adding Jquery! changing the order solved everything, thank you for the console tipp!